# How do I easily resize a wallpaper for my screen?

Tags: desktop-background, image-processing

I like to use wallpapers from [Interfacelift](http://interfacelift.com/wallpaper/downloads/date/any/) but not all the wallpapers are my screen's resolution and I was wondering what the best/easiest method would be to resize them to fit.

I tried installing the nautilus resize extension but it never showed up. I've heard a bit about Phatch, but that it was no longer being developed.

Comment: You should first search askubuntu. There are a few questions similar. For example: http://askubuntu.com/questions/144085/resize-images-to-specific-height-value-in-imagemagick and http://askubuntu.com/questions/1164/how-to-easily-resize-images . I just searched for "resize image".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1. Use the Nautilus Image Converter extension

> **Note:** You must logout/login after installing any Nautilus extensions for them to work!

- Install `nautilus-image-converter` from the Software Center:

  [image]
- Logout and login. Then open the folder where you saved the image, and right-click on it. Then click on *Resize Image...*:

  [image]
- You can set a custom size as shown. "In Place" will resize the existing file, while "Append" will save a new version:

  [image]

#### 2. If available, the easiest option is to download the right size in the first place.

*InterfaceLift*, the site you prefer, has LOTS of options for download sizes, which almost surely includes your screen size. If you select the right size when downloading, that's the easiest method:

[image]

Comment: The thing about that is not all the wallpapers support all resolutions, so some wallpapers are only for certain resolutions and others with my resolution aren't even displayed.

Comment: The Nautilus extension(s) work, you just have to logout/login after installing. See edited answer.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of resizing, you can make your wallpaper fill the screen from the Right Click **change Desktop background** options.

You can try the *`tile, zoom , center ,scale, fill, span`* options to desired one.

[image: Settings > Appearance dialog]

Comment: Can we get this thing in Ubuntu 20.04 ?

Answer (score 2):

In modern Ubuntu, it appears the only way to get scaling control of your background is through gnome-tweaks.  It is available through "software".[tweaks and background settings side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heTjE.png)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could also use **Firefox** to set wallpaper, it has options for resizing wallpaper.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Gimp and resize the image.

Alternatively you could also install Gwenview.

Both work great.

Comment: IMHO installing Gimp is overkill for occasional resizing.

Comment: I think Gimp is necessary IMHO, but then again I am the kind of person who will open Gimp in free time and just draw.